# FFT Plot Axis Confirmation

Tags: fft

I have a 4096 sequence of FFT coefficient. All of which a real values. My sampling frequency is also 4096 samples per seconds. Now I want to make a plot. I know my Y axis would be my FFT magnitude values, but what would my x- axis be. Would it be my sampling frequency, that is 1,2,3,4.........4096?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short snippet of code that returns the domain of the FFT depending on if you have the onesided or twosided FFT. This is from some code I posted on a somewhat related question [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/re-implementing-the-spectrogram-function-from-matlab/13077#13077).

```
% Nfft - FFT size
% Fs - Sampling frequency in Hz
% oneside - flag indicating FFT results will be onesided or two sided

% Compute the frequency vector
if oneside == true
  f = fs * (0:Nfft/2).'./Nfft;
else
  f = fs * (-Nfft/2:Nfft/2-1).'./Nfft;
end
```